# I want to change a column of month numbers in a dataframe to month name (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of month numbers in a dataframe and want to change it to month name, so I used this:

```
df['monthName'] = df['monthNumber'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[x])
```

But it throws me the following error:

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Please suggest me what are the ways to resolve this. I am new to python and spark

Edit1: I m using Spark 2.1.1 and Python 2.7.6

This is my code for Airline data Analysis.

```
df_withDelay = df_mappedCarrierNames.filter(df_mappedCarrierNames.ArrDelay > 0)
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df_withDelay,"SFO_ArrDelayAnalysisTable")
df_SFOArrDelay = sqlContext.sql \
                      ("select sfo.Month, sum(sfo.ArrDelay) as TotalArrivalDelay \
                      from SFO_ArrDelayAnalysisTable sfo \
                      where (sfo.Dest = 'SFO') \
                      group by sfo.Month")
```

I am trying to plot a graph with Month vs ArrDelay. From the above code I am getting Month as number. So I tried with the below option

```
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(x)], StringType())
new_df_mappedCarrierNames = df_mappedCarrierNames.select(*[udf(column).alias(name) if column == name else column for column in df_mappedCarrierNames.columns])
```

it works but, in my graph it's not in sorted order. whereas if I use the month numbers, it is in sorted order. My issue is in finding out how to map month numbers to month names in sorted order from Jan to dec.
Thanks in advance for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the clean solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

#1
month_lst = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
#2
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( [(1, "a", 23.0), (3, "B", -23.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

name = 'x1'
#3
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: month_lst[int(x%12) - 1], StringType())
new_df = df.select(*[udf(column).alias(name) if column == name else column for column in df.columns])
```

## 1

You build a dictionary

## 2

Define a dataframe and select the column
3
`month_lst[int(x%12) - 1]` This Is the important part, where i only assume the input is a float, and return a value from the list

If you need more help, pleas add a comment,

Comment: Yeey, well that supposed to be setps not options, but all in all yeeey,
please mark my answer as solution ;) thx!

Comment: I used udf and withColumn. Introduced a new column applying the udf for that column udf = F.UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(x)], StringType())
df_withDelay_month = df_withDelay.withColumn('MonthName', udf("Month"))

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using UDFs if possible (as they don't scale well). Try the combination of to_date(), date_format() and casting to integer:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.withColumn('monthNumber', date_format(to_date(col('monthName'), 'MMMMM'), 'MM').cast('int'))
```

Details of date formatting codes:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html

Comment: I agree a udf should be avoided, but this answer results in month numbers when the op ask for "month name"

Answer (score 2):

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
if 'date' column has a date format
.withColumn("month", F.date_format(F.col("date"), 'MMMM'))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps :
input 
May 20  2012

process

```
df_train = df_train.withColumn("dates", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df_train.dates, 'MMMMM dd  yyy')))
```

Output : 2012-05-20 00:00:00

```
month_udf = udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%B"), returnType = StringType())
dftest = df_train.withColumn("monthname", month_udf(df_train.dates))
```

Output : May